# updateMany() on array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

In my application i have a collection called `Blog` and i run this query every 24h

```
  await Blog.updateMany({}, [
    {
      $set: {
        viewed: {
          $add: [{ $size: "$visitorIps" }, "$viewed"]
        },
        visitorIps: []
      }
    }
  ]);
```

My problem is that i have a second collection called `Users`.
Inside of Users i have an array called `posts` and here are all posts from that user saved.

```
{
   _id: 234klj2ö34,
   user: "Max",
   posts: [
      {
         _id: 5dgewef323523,
         name: "My first blogpost",
         content: "...",
         viewed: 0,
         visitorIps: ["192.168.23.12"]
      }
   ]
}
```

Now i need the same query on my second collection for each array. How do i do it? I tried something like this but it doesnt worked:

```
  await User.updateMany({}, [
    {
      $set: {
        "posts.$[].viewed: {
          $add: [{ $size: "posts.$[].visitorIps" }, "posts.$[].viewed"]
        },
        "posts.$[].visitorIps": []
      }
    }
  ]);
```

But thats completely wrong. Could somebody help me here out?

Comment: I doubt that is possible. Because `$add, $size` are aggregate operators which works with $set aggregate update. Even if you use `$[]` or `$[element]`, it is not possible to use `$add, $size, $inc` with this requirement. How about writing to another collection with `$out`?

Comment: @Gibbs i think `$out` is not that what i am looking for. Is it possible to archive this with an aggregation? This task will be executed every 24h or every 3rd or 4th day so speed doesnt matter that much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html),

- your logic and code remain same for `viewed` and `visitorIps`
- [$mergeObjects](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/index.html) will merge current cursor fields and `viewed` and `visitorIps` that we have calculated

```
await User.updateMany({},
    [{
        $set: {
            posts: {
                $map: {
                    input: "$posts",
                    as: "post",
                    in: {
                        $mergeObjects: [
                            "$$post",
                            {
                                "viewed": {
                                    $add: [{ $size: "$$post.visitorIps" }, "$$post.viewed"]
                                },
                                "visitorIps": []
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }]
)
```

Comment: Are you sure that this will work? `Update operation must contain atomic operator` - Is it version specific?

Comment: try to use in mongo shell, because sometime this is not supporting in another platform, shell version should be 4.2

Comment: I have come across this inconsistencies multiple times but couldn't explain the reason why succeeds at shell but not via 3t. However, solution looks promising to me

Comment: because 3t shell version can be down, yes i can able to check mongo shell version, but i don't know how to check 3t shell version.

Comment: i will check it out soon

Comment: amazing, just copy / paste and it works without problem